# How can I easily use a COM component in Native Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, activex

I am trying to build an app that uses a COM component in VisualStudio ´05
in native C++.
The mix of native and managed desciptions of things in the MSDN totally wrecked my
brain. (I think the MSDN is a total mess in that respect)
I need a short and simple native C++ sample of code to load my Component
and make it usable.
I am ok with the compiler creating wrappers and the like.

Please don't advise me to use the dialog based MFC example, because
it does not work with this component and is in itself a huge 
pile of c... code.

Can this be an issue native com vs managed com?

I am totally lost, please give me some bearings...

EDIT: Thanks for all the help.
My problem is that all I have is a registered dll (actually the OCX, see below)
. I (personally) know
what the Interface should look like, but how do I tell my program?
There are no headers that define
IDs for Interfaces that I could use. But I read that the c++ compiler
can extract and wrap it up for me. Anyone know how this is done?

CLARIFICATION: I have only the OCX and a clue from the documentation
of the component, what methods it should expose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fully working example (exactly what you need) from my blog article: [How to Call COM Object from Visual Studio C++?](https://helloacm.com/how-to-call-com-object-from-visual-studio-c/)

```
// https://helloacm.com/how-to-call-com-object-from-visual-studio-c/
#include <iostream>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <unknwn.h>
#include <Propvarutil.h>
#import "wshom.ocx" no_namespace, raw_interfaces_only  

using namespace std;

int main() {
    HRESULT hr;
    CLSID clsid;
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);  
    CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("WScript.Shell"), &clsid);   
    IWshShell *pApp = nullptr;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IWshShell), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID *>(&pApp));
    if (FAILED(hr) || pApp == nullptr) {
        throw "Cannot Create COM Object";
    }
    int out;
    VARIANT s;
    InitVariantFromInt32(0, &s);
    VARIANT title;
    InitVariantFromString(PCWSTR(L"title"), &title);
    VARIANT type;
    InitVariantFromInt32(4096, &type);
    BSTR msg = ::SysAllocString(L"Hello from https://helloacm.com");
    pApp->Popup(msg, &s, &title, &type, &out);
    CoUninitialize();
    cout << "Out = " << out;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I applaud your efforts to go with native C++ to deal with COM - you need to go through the pain to truly appreciate today's luxurious (managed) development environment :)

Back when the world (and I) were younger, Kraig Brockshmidt's book "[Inside OLE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556158432)" was **the** tome for making sense of COM (before COM even was COM). This book predates managed code, so no chance of managed confusion here. There's a second edition, too.

Don Box's books "[Essential COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634465)" and "[Effective COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379686)" were later, but welcome additions to the store of (unmanaged) COM knowledge.

However, if your wallet doesn't extend to acquiring these dusty old books, the Microsoft COM tutorial material [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263810(VS.60).aspx) could help set you on the right track.

Happy hacking.

Comment: Well. Thanks :). I could say: "I don't read!" but that would not be a good career move, would it ;)

Answer (score 4):

The bare minimums for instantiating a COM object are as follows:

1) Must have a COM apartment available.

This is accomplished by most applications by calling CoInitialize / CoInitializeEx to setup the COM library and the initial COM apartment if it is the first time for a process.

2) Call CoCreateInstance / CoCreateInstanceEx to create an object, and specify flags to denote how it will be instantiated.

3) Properly balance calls of AddRef and Release on the interfaces of any COM components that you create, calling the last Release() when you are done using a COM component.

-

In a managed application, #1 is almost always handled for you. #2 is abstracted away if you import a reference to a COM library, and you can just use the imported names as if they were .NET class definitions and such. #3 is automatically handled for you, but your needs may vary. Unfortunately, there are sometimes quirks in how references are handled in managed applications, which can cause COM objects to stick around longer than intended. The Marshal helper class in System.Runtime has methods that can help you out there if you encounter issues.

-

In an unmanaged application, you will have to do some legwork if you are creating an application from scratch.

1. Call CoInitialize/CoInitializeEx early in your application's main thread to setup the apartment.
2. When your application's main thread is about to exit, call CoUninitialize() to close out the apartment.
3. For additional threads that you create, you should also call CoInitialize/CoInitializeEx when they start if you need to use COM objects from those threads. Also, depending on your application you may want to set the apartment parameters.
4. For those threads, also call CoUninitialize() when they are exiting to cleanup properly.

Answer (score 3):

I use a combination of ATL smart COM pointers and the ATL::CAxWindow class for COM objects and components.  I find the smart pointers particularly easy to use.

http://www.murrayc.com/learning/windows/usecomfromatl.shtml

http://76.105.92.243/notes/atlcom.html#import

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx242b61%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links, number 2 looks really promising. It will take till tomorrow to parse all this :|

Comment: I'm interested to know why someone voted this down!  I was only trying to help.

Comment: Well and you succeded. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you gave a little more information about what you're exactly doing.  Do you know what interfaces the object implements, etc?

In general though, the API that you can Google for more specific help is CoCreateInstance.  You'll need to pass it the GUID of the object you want to play with.  All COM objects implement the IUnknown interface, and you can query for any others it might have.  So some sample pseudocode to get you started might look something like:

```
CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED );
CoCreateInstance( CLSID,
                       ptrIUnknown,
                       ClassCxt, // generally CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                       riid , // reference id
                       (void **)&pRequest); // the interface that corresponds to the riid
```

Here you can query additional interfaces using the IUnknown interface you got from the ptrIUnknown.

Then clean up with

```
CoUninitialize()
```

Don Box's Essential COM is a great book on this topic.  Also, just for testing how your COM object works, using something like VBScript makes this super easy.  Also, it's probably worthy of note that the GUID of the class ID is stored in a somewhat unusual way, so if you're just ripping a GUID from the registry, you might have some trouble figuring out the ordering.  That's probably for a different question though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using #import from Visual C++. This will create smart pointer wrappers for the interfaces.